# Improving summing algorithm for 2048 game developed with PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I challenged myself to improve my skills by doing some individual projects and for now I am stuck with the 2048.

I have the text file which stores the present values of the game.

> 128 64 32 16 32 8 8 8 16 4 4 4 8 2 2 2

```
<?php
$logs = file("logs-2048.txt");
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    file_put_contents('logs-2048.txt', '');
    $tableValues = [];

    $arrayLine = explode(" ", $logs[0]);
    for($g=0; $g<4; $g++) {
        $newLine = [];
        for($h=0; $h<4; $h++) {
            array_push($newLine, htmlspecialchars($arrayLine[$g*4+$h]));
        }
        array_push($tableValues, $newLine);
    }

    $direction = $_POST["action-joueur"];
    $string = "";

    if($direction == "^") {
        for($g = 0; $g < 3; $g++) {
            for ($h = 0; $h < 4; $h++) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
                    if ($tableValues[$i][$h] == $tableValues[$i+1][$h] || $tableValues[$i][$h] == 0) {
                        $tableValues[$i][$h] += $tableValues[$i+1][$h];
                        $tableValues[$i+1][$h] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else if ($direction == "v") {
        //Almost simillar stuff as for ^
    } else if ($direction == "<") {
        //Almost similar stuff as for ^
    } else if ($direction == ">") {
        //Almost similar stuff as for ^
    }

    $arrayEmpty = [];
    for($g = 0; $g < 4; $g++) {
        for($h = 0; $h < 4; $h++) {
            if($tableValues[$g][$h] == 0) {
                array_push($arrayEmpty, [$g, $h]);
            }
        }
    }
    $findRand = mt_rand(0, count($arrayEmpty)-1);
    $tableValues[$arrayEmpty[$findRand][0]][$arrayEmpty[$findRand][1]] = 2;

    for($g = 0; $g < 4; $g++) {
        for ($h = 0; $h < 4; $h++) {
            $string = $string.$tableValues[$g][$h]." ";
        }
    }
    file_put_contents("logs-2048.txt", $string);
}
?>
```

The first loop is to parse the array that I take from the file, and convert it to a 2 dimensional array(table).

The problem is in the next 4 nested loops which does the summing, I can't figure how can I do other way then just use another loop(first one for each nested loop) which goes 3 times back if some numbers were stuck somewhere adding themselves (EX. 2 2 2 2 in first column => 4 2 2 0 => 4 4 0 0 => 8 0 0 0).

I am 100% sure that the algorithms for summing is terribly inefficient, but I can't figure out what solution I can provide to make it faster and more intuitive, then have 4 for's... I tried also to look at different resources on internet but it's pretty messed up for me because I am starting with php.

> Yes, I know that php isn't the best way to do, I'll do myself with
>   Javascript, but I need it for learning, any ideas or tips  to improve the algorithm will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try repeatedly summing the first 2 summable numbers until there are no more summations which can be performed

Comment: In other words, instead of repeatedly nesting for loops, put the for loops which perform a single pass on your data structure inside a while loop which repeatedly executes until no changes occur.

Comment: I forgot about the while loop, I will try both using functions or boolean variables to test the solution, is this an efficient/normal way(in general the algorithm)?

Comment: There are more efficient ways, but this is a simple and not terribly inefficient way of doing it for small boards. Don't go crazy trying to optimize things if you don't need to.

Comment: Okey, thanks a lot :)